# Why does the hyperref package changes encoding of font commands?

Tags: xetex, hyperref

If you compile the following document with hyperref using `XeLaTeX` you will see that the encoding of the text commands is changed by the`hyperref` package to "PU" encoding. Why is this necessary?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\meaning\textasciitilde\\
\meaning\textcelsius\\
\meaning\"\\
\meaning\NG\\
\meaning\k\\

\end{document}
```

Are there any "gotchas" to watch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't load `hyperref`, then you'd get

```
macro:->\T1-cmd \textasciitilde \T1\textasciitilde
```

although the default encoding is `EU1` (or `EU2` with LuaLaTeX).

With `hyperref` you get

```
macro:->\PU-cmd \textasciitilde \PU\textasciitilde
```

because `puenc.def` has been loaded later. The macro `\PU-cmd` looks for two arguments and does

```
\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
  \@inmathwarn#1%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\cf@encoding\string#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ?\string#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\def\csname ?\string#1\endcsname{\TextSymbolUnavailable#1}
    \fi
    \global\expandafter\let\csname\cf@encoding\string#1\expandafter\endcsname 
      \csname ?\string#1\endcsname
  \fi
  \csname\cf@encoding\string#1\expandafter\endcsname
\else
  \noexpand#1%
\fi
```

The arguments are `\textasciitilde` and `\PU\textasciitilde` (which is one token).

In normal typesetting, `\ifx\protect\typeset@protect` is true, so `\@inmathwarn\textasciitilde` is expanded, but it does

```
\ifmmode \@latex@warning {Command \protect #1 invalid in math mode}\fi
```

so nothing happens unless we're in math mode. Then LaTeX checks whether

```
\EU1\textasciitilde
```

(one token) is defined which it is: `\cf@encoding` is expanded to the current output encoding. If it weren't, in the usual sense that `\EU1\textasciitilde` is equivalent to `\relax` or undefined, LaTeX would look for `\?\textasciitilde` (a default text command) and, if a definition for it is missing, an error message would be defined for further usage `\EU1\textasciitilde` would be globally made  equivalent to `\?\textasciitilde`.

Finally, `\EU1\textasciitilde` is expanded.

In case the first conditional is false (that is, we're writing to files or in other special places), just `\noexpand\textasciitilde` would remain in the input stream.

You see that `PU` never intervenes, unless `\cf@encoding` *is* `PU`, which happens when `hyperref` is doing its work of writing the bookmarks.

Comment: So in a nutshell hyperref always uses its own encoding (PU) for bookmarks?

Comment: Yes, `PU` or `PD1`, depending on the engine or options to `hyperref` (with the `unicode` option `PU` is forced also for `pdflatex`). Also hyperlinks use the internal `hyperref` encoding, I guess.

Comment: Yes, PD1 (PDFDocEncoding) or PU (Unicode/UTF16-BE). Bookmarks are written as simple strings into the PDF file without access to the font machinery of TeX.