# Would the redefinition of \k and \H cause trouble?

Tags: macros, hyperref

In my current document, the commands `\k` and `\H` are defined to be `\PU-cmd\k\Pu\k` and `\PU-cmd\H\Pu\H`, which seems to be part of the package `hyperref`. However, for the convenience, I redefined them as follows:

```
\def\k{\Bbbk}
\def\H{\mathbb{H}}
```

My question is, would these redefinitions cause serious trouble? It seems fine in my document, but I'm afraid if I have broken some important internal commands and the retribution shall come sooner or later.

Comment: Untested: You can use \newcommand instead of \def. If the comment already exists, then you will get sn error.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I already know that these commands exist, and that's why I'm asking if it is safe to *re*-define them.

Comment: @marquinho Thank you this! Knowing that `\k` and `\H` are diacritics, I think it would be safe (for me) to redefine them, as I'm using Unicode engines and can type in the accented letters directly when needed.

Comment: [EDIT: sorry for deleting my former comment!] Those are standard LaTeX diacritics, aren't they? `\H` is a long Hungarian umlaut as in "ő" and `\k` is a Polish ogonek as in "ą" ([source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes)). `hyperref` [does change the encoding to PU, for use in a PDF, but not the meaning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198810). So redefining them wouldn't break hyperref, **if** you never use those commands for diacritics

Comment: They aren't commands specific to hyperref, the accents are defined without them too, hyperref only adds its encoding. I wouldn't redefine them. These commands are standard LaTeX commands and you can't know if some command from some package internally uses \k or \H to produce an accent (it doesn't matter if you use an unicode engine or not).

Comment: When your bibliography cites a paper by “Erdős and Szczęsny” you'll know why redefining `\k` and `\H` is a bad idea. Using `\kk` and `\HH` is even more semantic, besides avoiding the problem of redefinition.

Comment: Crosslink to related question: [macros - How to redefine one-letter commands? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282794/how-to-redefine-one-letter-commands) [Short names for macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cite a paper by “Erdős and Szczęsny”, you'll know why redefining `\k` and `\H` is a bad idea.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author={Erdős, P. and Szczęsny, W.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2022},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\renewcommand\k{\Bbbk}
\renewcommand\H{\mathbb{H}}

\begin{document}

$\k+\H$ \cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The console after running LaTeX and BibTeX and LaTeX again:

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathbb allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.4 P.~Erdő
            s and W.~Szczęsny.
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.4 P.~Erdős and W.~Szczę
                           sny.
```

Comment: It is not bad idea to redefine sort control sequences at user level. It is bad idea to use them in laTeX as an internal control sequences. Moreover, it is only problem with old LaTeX, non-unicode LaTeX and non-Unicode Bibtex. With Unicode-ready software this problem is not occur.

Comment: @wipet Uh? Try and redefine `\tenrm` in plain TeX. Or `\box`. The latter is a very nice name for my command, isn't it?

Comment: Try to redefine `\box` or `\fi` or whatever in OpTeX. Nothing horrible happens. OpTeX will work without problems.

Comment: @wipet That's completely irrelevant. LaTeX users may not want to use XeTeX or LuaTeX and they may *need* to input `Erd\H{o}s` because they are not required to know how to use Unicode input. And there are thousands (or millions) of documents that need to be typeset without having to change them. That's not so small a difference, is it?

Comment: Please allow me to ask one more question, what if I define `\k` and `\H` to be my meaning in math mode while keep the original meaning in text mode, using `\mode_if_math:TF`?

Comment: @Jinwen It *should* work, but I wouldn't recommend it: uselessly confusing. I stand with my opinion that `\kk` and `\HH` are more semantic.

Comment: @egreg OK, thank you, that is indeed a good suggestion.